# How does facebook and pinterest implement their LIKE methods

Tags: ios, uibutton, selector

assume they don't have APIs, how do they implement the LIKE buttons?

for eg. I set the a button in the view

```
UIButton *likeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [likeButton setTitle:@"Like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [likeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    likeButton.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 100,30);
```

with a selector to detect the lIKE button

```
[likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likeButtonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

is it possible to pass a USER to the likeButtonPressedAction selector, so that I know which User the LIKE was pressed? i.e. I can detect if the LIKE button was pressed, But I'm not sure how to detect who that LIKE belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the best way is to use Tags to recognize required views.